# How to call a nav webservice from android

Tags: android, nav

I want to call web service running in Microsoft Dynamics nav ERP i am using ksoap2 library but problem is every time i run my application it throws

```
java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:7047 - Connection refused
```

Microsoft Dynamics nav is using NTLM authentication may that is the problem, please give any suggestion to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
String namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/NavisionWS";
String url = "http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Codeunit/NavisionWS";   
String soap_action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/NavisionWS:GetLoginInfo";
String method_name = "GetLoginInfo";
try
        {
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);    
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

               envelope.dotNet = true;   
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);   
               HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);    
               transport.call(soap_action, envelope); // Receive Error here!
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                    great = result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
                 great = e.toString();
                 Toast.makeText(this, great, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IP Address instead of Localhost to connect to webservice from Android

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` to your manifest?

Comment: I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in manifest

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a device to run your application?

Comment: Currently using emulator and the microsoft dynamics nav is running on my system. I am trying ntlm authentication code found at samba site and url is opening from my browser, it asks for system user and password then shows the content.

Comment: I got the solution. url should be "http://10.0.2.2:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Codeunit/NavisionWS" instead of "http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Codeunit/NavisionWS"

Comment: @kadhirvel Answer your own question, may be helpful to others :)