# android consumption of navision web service

Tags: android, service, web, navision, dynamics-nav

I need to consume the NAV web service from android.
I got the "Letters" codeunit with "Upper" function.

I have setup a NAV web service (NTLM authentication) on my PC and turned off the firewall (so that this service is visible on other devices in my network). The service can be accessed in the browser (also on the adroid device) after inputting the login/pass (of my PC account).
If i use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685255/how-to-call-a-nav-webservice-from-android) it crashes on "call" with END_DOCUMENT null exception...
Is that because of the authentication?

If i use this code to connect

> ```
> HttpGet request = new
> HttpGet("http://[myPC'sIP]:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/SystemService");
> HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
> ```

i get 401 error, but just specifying the IP

> ```
> HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://[myPC'sIP]");
> HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
> ```

returns code 200 (ok)
How can I send the credentials? I tried several ways, but result is always the same...
Do you have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I use soap_action for doing the same and its working like charm, see if below code helps you:

```
String namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/NavisionWS";
String url = "http://IP:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Codeunit/NavisionWS";   
String soap_action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/NavisionWS:GetLoginInfo";
String method_name = "GetLoginInfo";
try
        {
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);    
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

               envelope.dotNet = true;   
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);   
               HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);    
               transport.call(soap_action, envelope); // Receive Error here!
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                    great = result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
                 great = e.toString();
                 Toast.makeText(this, great, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: But doesn't it request login/pass? When you enter "http://IP:7037/DynamicsNAV/WS/SystemService" in the browser it asks me for credentials... Under which account your NAV Server is running?

Comment: You can use java.net.Authenticator for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Add Below Jars 
**jcifs-1.3.17.jar** 
**ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

2) Create these java classes
**JCIFSEngine.java**

```
package com.demo.Authentication;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.NtlmFlags;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;
import jcifs.util.Base64;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngine;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineException;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Class taken from http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html
 */
public final class JCIFSEngine implements NTLMEngine {

    private static final int TYPE_1_FLAGS =
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56 |
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128 |
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2 |
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN |
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET;

    public String generateType1Msg(final String domain, final String workstation)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        final Type1Message type1Message = new Type1Message(TYPE_1_FLAGS, domain, workstation);
        return Base64.encode(type1Message.toByteArray());
    }

    public String generateType3Msg(final String username, final String password,
            final String domain, final String workstation, final String challenge)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        Type2Message type2Message;
        try {
            type2Message = new Type2Message(Base64.decode(challenge));
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            throw new NTLMEngineException("Invalid NTLM type 2 message", exception);
        }
        final int type2Flags = type2Message.getFlags();
        final int type3Flags = type2Flags
                & (0xffffffff ^ (NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER));
        final Type3Message type3Message = new Type3Message(type2Message, password, domain,
                username, workstation, type3Flags);
        return Base64.encode(type3Message.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

**NtlmTransport.java**

```
package com.demo.Authentication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnection;
import org.ksoap2.transport.Transport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;


public class NtlmTransport extends Transport {

    static final String ENCODING = "utf-8";

    private final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private final HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    private String urlString;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String ntDomain;
    private String ntWorkstation;
    public static String AuthenticationCode;

    public NtlmTransport(String url, String user, String password,
            String domain, String workStation) {
this.urlString = url;
this.user = user;
this.password = password;
this.ntDomain = domain;
this.ntWorkstation = workStation;

}

    public void setCredentials(String url, String user, String password,
                               String domain, String workStation) {
        this.urlString = url;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.ntDomain = domain;
        this.ntWorkstation = workStation;

    }

    public List call(String targetNamespace, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        return call(targetNamespace, envelope, headers, null);
    }

    public List call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers, File outputFile)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        if (outputFile != null) {
            // implemented in HttpTransportSE if you are willing to port..
            throw new RuntimeException("Writing to file not supported");
        }
        HttpResponse resp = null;

        setupNtlm(urlString, user, password);

        try {
            // URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

            setHeaders(soapAction, envelope, httppost, headers);

            resp = client.execute(httppost, localContext);
            HttpEntity respEntity = resp.getEntity();


            InputStream is = respEntity.getContent();
            parseResponse(envelope, is);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("RESPONSE STATUS CODE :"+resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (resp != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(resp.getAllHeaders());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setHeaders(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, HttpPost httppost, List headers) {
        byte[] requestData = null;
        try {
            requestData = createRequestData(envelope);
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
        }
        ByteArrayEntity byteArrayEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(requestData);
        httppost.setEntity(byteArrayEntity);
        httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.USER_AGENT);
        // SOAPAction is not a valid header for VER12 so do not add
        // it
        // @see "http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=67
        if (envelope.version != SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER12) {
            httppost.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        }

        if (envelope.version == SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER12) {
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", Transport.CONTENT_TYPE_SOAP_XML_CHARSET_UTF_8);
        } else {
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", Transport.CONTENT_TYPE_XML_CHARSET_UTF_8);
        }

        // Pass the headers provided by the user along with the call
        if (headers != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                HeaderProperty hp = (HeaderProperty) headers.get(i);
                httppost.addHeader(hp.getKey(), hp.getValue());
            }
        }
    }


    // Try to execute a cheap method first. This will trigger NTLM authentication
    public void setupNtlm(String dummyUrl, String userId, String password) {
        try {

            ((AbstractHttpClient) client).getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());

            NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(userId, password, ntWorkstation, ntDomain);
            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(dummyUrl);

            HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpget, localContext);
            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
            Header[] hArray = response1.getAllHeaders();
            int size = hArray.length;
            AuthenticationCode = String.valueOf(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AUTHENTICATION STATUS CODE :"+response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
           /* for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
                Header h = hArray[i];
                if (h.getName().equals("WWW-Authenticate")) {
                    entity1.consumeContent();
                    throw new Exception("Failed Authentication");
                }
            }*/

            entity1.consumeContent();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        //NTLM Scheme factory
    private class NTLMSchemeFactory implements AuthSchemeFactory {
        public AuthScheme newInstance(final HttpParams params) {
        // see http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/
        // manipulating-sharepoint-list-items-with-android-java-and-ntlm-authentication/
            return new NTLMScheme(new JCIFSEngine());
        }
    }

    public ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException
    {
        throw new IOException("Not using ServiceConnection in transport");
    }

    public String getHost() {
        String retVal = null;
        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getHost();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        int retVal = -1;
        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getPort();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        String retVal = null;
        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getPath();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

3)
Call this method with paramater url,"username","password","domainName","SystemName"

```
 NtlmTransport ntlm = new NtlmTransport(url, "username", "password", "domainName","SystemName");
```

4) Send Soap Request which consist of Soap Envelope.

```
 ntlm.call("namespace/methodname", soapEnvelope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creation of another web service (written on C#, running on the same PC where NAV server runs) which reads NAV service and android communicates with NAV WS through this C# WS

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried to use

```
var httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
NTCredentials nt = new NTCredentials("user", "pass", "", "domain");
httpClient.GetCredentialsProvider().SetCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, nt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how http authentication is [supposed to work](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2). You can use fiddler to see what your intermediary is doing. If you want to get rid of it you'll have to do the same thing :)

That being said authentication with Navision is no picnic as it uses SPNEGO or NTLM. If you can configure for NTLM you might be able to use [android-ntlm](https://github.com/masconsult/android-ntlm) to get the job done. Looks similar to pungggi's answer except for `httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());`